# how can I specify a popup to show only for a specific layer in openLayers 3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, popup

I am using the function to define popup contents in a map, and right now, it createa a popup for every feature I click on the map, no matter what layer it is in. I would like this popup to appear only for features within one layer. I'm sure there is a way I can specify this in the function, but I'm not sure how. I tried using this for line 6 `if (feature && layer === layerVector) {` but it gave me an error saying that layer is undefined. layerVector is the variable name for the layer I want to use the popup for. Can anyone help? Here is the code:

```
map.on('click', function(evt) {
  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
      function(feature, layer) {
        return feature;
      });
  if (feature) {
    popup.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
      content.innerHTML = '<b>Parcel No: </b>'+
      feature.get('parcel')+'<br>'+
      '<b>Owner: </b>'+
      feature.get('primowner')
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When doing [forEachFeatureAtPixel](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.Map.html#forEachFeatureAtPixel), you should do any filtrering inside the callback function. You have the *feature* and it's *layer* available as arguments.

This would return the first clicked feature:

```
var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel,
  function(feature, layer) {
    return feature;
  }
);
```

This would return the first clicked feature in `targetLayer`:

```
var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel,
  function(feature, layer) {
    if (layer == targetLayer) {
      return feature;
    }
  }
);
```

But when you know that you are only interested in a set of specific layers, a simple optimization is to use the fourth argument: the layer filter function.

The layer filter function is called once for each vector layer, and determines if the layer should be used when looking for features at the given pixel. The code above would trigger an unnecessary spatial lookup in all vector layers, while the code below will only look for matching features in `targetLayer`:

```
var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel,
  function (feature, layer) {
    return feature;
  },
  this, // third argument, determines 'this' for the callback
  function (layer) {
    return layer == targetLayer;
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply, that works perfectly. I don't quite understand how tthe last bit of code that you posted works though

Answer (score 0):

just return an object holding feature and layer and not only feature. Then access the layer through object. something like that:

```
map.on('click', function (evt) {
    var obj = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,

    function (feature, layer) {
        return [feature,layer];
    });
    console.log(obj)
    if (obj) {
        console.info("layer is",obj[1]);
        var feature =obj[0];
        var layer= obj[1];
        if(layer === featureOverlay){
        alert("yes is my layer!!!");
        popup.setPosition(evt.coordinate);
        //$(container).popover({
        //'placement': 'top',
        //'html': true,
        content.innerHTML = '<b>Parcel No: </b>' + feature.get('parcel') + '<br>' +
            '<b>Owner: </b>' + feature.get('primowner')
        }  
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried to use this code, but I don't understand what it's telling me in the console. It seems to work in firefox, but in chrome the popup does not appear. In firefox, when it does return the popup, it's very slow now. Also with firefox, the popup doesn't show the first couple of times I click on features where it should show.

Comment: Its your code but I just  return [fetaure, layer] instead of feature only. console info returns the layer object, dont expect to get the layer name or a human readable string. If you set an attribute like "NAME" when initialising the layer then you may get it back like so layer.get('NAME'). The slowness is strange as returning just one more object can not make the browser getting slow. Check your code or provide a fiddle to enlighten us

Comment: Here is a link to a fiddle, I did not include your code. But you can see what else is in there. I am thinking that maybe what might be best is to add the geolocFeature as an overlay rather than load it into a vector layer. https://jsfiddle.net/kflaw/yasL746r/

Comment: Ok I tried that and it didn't change the behavior.

Comment: Ok I managed to make the fiddle working. So where are the parcels??? I mean in which area I may find parcels??? You need to check whether click is taking place on geoloc or parcels. right????? and if on parcel popup else not popup. right?????

Comment: only in the boise area right now, and yes, the only other feature on the map right now besides the parcels is the geolocation marker, and I want the popups for the parcels only. Also the mouse changes when you hover over a feature, this should really only be specific now to features that have popups

Comment: I cannt get any parcels even when I zoom to the boise area (this is US. right?) I even changed to strategy to bbox. but no parcels. the responce i get back for parcels is {"type":"FeatureCollection","totalFeatures":0,"features":[],"crs":null}. but anyway check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/efmsot3d/

Comment: They are there, you have to zoom in quite a bit for them to draw. I'll check your fiddle thanks for taking a look I appreciate it!

Comment: I can see in your fiddle that there is no a longer a popup for the geolocation marker, but when I zoom to the parcels, the popup shows when i click on a parcel feature but the contents are blank. I'll keep looking at it

Comment: try it again. I made a few changes. though, I can not see the parcels in order to test prorperly. Can you see the parcels with my fiddle???? Or its just me?

Comment: try what @Alvin Lindstam suggest. Is more elegand.